# How does variable assignment in an expression work?

Tags: php, variables, expression, variable-assignment

This is a practice I've seen before, but not very often: A variable is assigned to a value at the same time the value itself is evaluated (or is it the expression itself that is evaluated?). Example:

```
// Outputs "The value is 1"
$value = 1;
if ($var = $value) {
    echo "The value is $var";
}
```

Seems to be the same as:

```
$value = 1;
$var = $value;
if ($var) {
    echo "The value is $var";
}
```

Another example:

```
// Outputs "The value is 1"
$value = 1;
echo "The value is ".$var = $value;
```

I've been using this a little bit to shorten up my code, mainly the first example: for evaluating the first variable or expression while assigning it to another within the same expression. Something like this:

```
if ($status = User::save($data)) {
    echo "User saved.";
}
// do something else with $status
```

This seems so basic, but I can't actually find any [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) on this, maybe I'm not sure where to look. I've only recently figured out how this works after seeing it for years, and I really like using it, but I don't want to use it haphazardly.

It makes code shorter, maybe not quite as clear to some, but definitely less repetitive. Are there any caveats with this method? Is this perfectly safe or are there any cases where it might fail or cause unexpected behavior? This doesn't seem to be a very common practice, so I was hoping to find an explanation before I start "going nuts" with it. If it *is* documented, links to the correct page will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php:

> PHP takes expressions much further, in the same way many other languages do. PHP is an expression-oriented language, in the sense that almost everything is an expression. Consider the example we've already dealt with, `$a = 5`. It's easy to see that there are two values involved here, the value of the integer constant `5`, and the value of `$a` which is being updated to 5 as well. But the truth is that there's one additional value involved here, and that's the value of the assignment itself. The assignment itself evaluates to the assigned value, in this case 5. In practice, it means that `$a = 5`, regardless of what it does, is an expression with the value 5. Thus, writing something like `$b = ($a = 5)` is like writing `$a = 5; $b = 5;` (a semicolon marks the end of a statement). Since assignments are parsed in a right to left order, you can also write `$b = $a = 5`.

Many people would argue that you shouldn't use this behaviour very often.  For instance, distinguishing between:

```
if ($a == 5) { ... }
```

and

```
if ($a = 5) { ... }
```

is tricky! The two common idiomatic ways of writing the above to distinguish them:

```
if (5 == $a) { ... }
if (($a = 5)) { ... }
```

The first is called a [yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions) and causes a syntax error if a equals character is left out. The latter won't behave any differently when run, but some code checkers will output warnings when the expression doesn't have the extra parentheses.

Comment: "there's one additional value involved here, and that's the value of the assignment itself" - That's the part I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php is what you probably need.

PHP expressions being evaluated in turn, in order from highest precedence to lower.
So, first we have assignment evaluated and then apply conditional statement on it. There is also some [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) magic involved, to convert return value to boolean on the fly

> Are there any caveats with this method?

Sure. If zero being a valid return value, your code may fail you. A common example is strpos() function:

```
if ($pos = strpos("a","aaa"))...
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that when used wisely this is "OK" to do then. Sorry to write such a "dumb" question but it's so rare to see this in practice. I get the part about what evaluates to "false" like `int(0)` or `string('0')`, that has to just be taken into consideration o a per-case basis.

Comment: @Wesley there is nothing dumb actually, a usual SO question is way dumber. Thats indeed unusual behavior, yet so familiar to PHP coders that it makes hard to explain. There are also many values counted as FALSE - empty string, NULL, empty array.

Comment: It was really the part that the expression `$a = $b;` actually *returns* the value of `$b` that I was missing. For example, I never knew that `$a = $b = $c;` would even work, let alone return a value.

Comment: I'm just not used to getting downvoted, and I scored one immediately, and now that this is over it seems so clear. Welcome back - I missed your brash commentary :)

Comment: @Wesley LOL i see now. Well, it wasn't me. I have no idea who can downvote such well-thought, well-phrased question asking a *link to documentation*

Answer (score 1):

The result of an assigment is the result of the right hand expression, so `$var = $value` evaluates to `$value`. Now, you have to take into account what exactly means `FALSE` or `TRUE` in PHP.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

```
FALSE:
 the boolean FALSE itself 
 the integer 0 (zero) 
 the float 0.0 (zero) 
 the empty string, and the string "0" 
 an array with zero elements 
 an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only) 
 the special type NULL (including unset variables) 
 SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

TRUE:
  everything not listed above
```

The ifs are hit if the assignment evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: Your first sentence clarifies this well. I get the part about "falseness", and testing now it seems we can use `$a = 2; if (($b = $a) === 2){echo $b;}` I never knew that. Thanks, sorry to burden SO with yet another basic question - it's just so uncommon to see this.

Answer (score 1):

> How does variable assignment in an expression work?

It's obvious, maybe too obvious, so I say it: Always the same. An expression is an [expression<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

Let's put it apart:

```
if ($var = $value)

[1] := if ([2])
[2] := $var = $value
```

1. Is an if expression. That is the boolean value of [2].
2. Is a variable assignment expression. Results in the value of `$value`.

A common mistake therefore is to write

```
if ($a = $b)
```

when it was meant to write

```
if ($a == $b)
```

can happen while typing.

In PHP basically "anything that has a value" is an expression.

Comment: If it were an expression then you'd be able to write `$b = if ($var = $value)`.  Also, the documentation doesn't describe it as such.

Comment: I think you're misleaded by the expectation that an expression must "return" something. With `if` you can express that the following statmeent / block is conditianlly further expressed. As for the documentation, look at the function example given close to the top of the page (first example), you find the link in the answer. In PHP nearly everything is an expression. Should be on that page as well.

Comment: That's what "expression" means; it's something that evaluates to a value (that's exactly what the first paragraph in your link says).  `if` is a "control structure", or "compound statement".

Comment: Despite the semantics (expression/statement), this clarifies it well, thanks hakre. I guess [2] returning the value was the part that seemed strange to me.

Comment: Maybe I have a bit more broad of view what the term expression means in a scripting language. You're right according the manual, it's most accurately described as *"anything that has a value"*. Edited the answer to reflect that better. The if expression is indeed noted inside the paranthesis, excluding the `if`.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Yeah, you need to know that before you can read it. Allows you to do: `$a = $b = 5` to assign `5` to `$a` and `$b` (first to `$b`, then to `$a`).

Comment: Testing now I see that this works too: `$a = 1; $b = $c = $d = $a;` - b, c, and d all now equal `1`. Strange.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Why strange? You assign `1` to `$a`. Then in the next statement `$a` is `1`. The other assignments as outlined in my previous comment (right to left).

Comment: It's strange because it is *unusual* to do something like that, but now I see how it works and it makes sense. Thanks again, wish I could accept all 4 answers because they all helped clarify this in a different way.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: You're welcome. That's what multiple answers are for: Different views and your decision to pick one of them :) - very kind of you!