# PHP | $value = $anothervalue = getValue() - does it have negative influence on performace?

Tags: php, coding-style

This question is about code optimalization: What is better for performance and why (the first example is cleaner for human being->programmer->me)?

```
$value = $anothervalue = getValue();
```

or

```
$anothervalue = $getValue;
$value = $anothervalue;
```

Comment: Talk about micro-optimization.  Which one do you find *easier to read?*  Use that one.

Comment: * [PHP freshmen wants to optimize...](http://qkme.me/35ksv1)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215292/how-does-variable-assignment-in-an-expression-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *real performance* issues.

Performance improvement is when you replaced 100 sql queries with 1 and reduced page generation time from 1 second to 0.0001s

As long as you cannot (can you?) measure the difference between 2 cases - use the one that is more readable and easy to maintain

Answer (score 2):

```
$value = $anothervalue = getValue();
```

I'd guess is probably the most efficient, and it looks much nicer, too. However! An optimization like this should not matter in terms of execution time *at all*, so feel free to use whichever is clearer *to you*.

Comment: Why do you think this could be the most efficient? (not my downvote BTW)

Comment: @The Nail: actually it should be more efficient, just because there is 1 statement, not 2 (so less work to parser) ;-) Though I wouldn't answer in this way ever (yes, because I would afraid of downvotes) )))

Comment: @TheNail: Parsing operations, it's just less tokens to work with. Also, it's less expressions to evaluate. And I also agree that it doesn't matter in the least.

Comment: It might actually be the other way round. The bytecode is almost the same, except that in the double assignment it uses an expression result, whereas the two statements both just use constants. So in the realm of irrelevant picoseconds, the two separate assignments might "win".

Answer (score 1):

It should have no influence on performance they perform the same operation IMO, although I prefer the later due to readability

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a [micro-optimization](/questions/tagged/micro-optimization).  There is absolutely no benefit to trying to determine which is faster, because even if one of them is (which I honestly doubt) then the difference will be so small as to make no practical difference in real life.

If you absolutely must find out one way or the other, then you could benchmark it.  Run a loop that does operation in the `$a = $b = func()` style, then run the same loop but using the `$a = func(); $b = $a` style instead.

As the difference is probably nearly non-existent, you'll need a very big loop, at least 100,000 iterations.