# PHP echo linking

Tags: php

How can I add a link to the following line?

```
if ($image) echo $image->resize('w=272&h=170');
```

I have tried adding something like

```
if ($image) echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'$image->resize('w=272&h=170')'</a>';
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? What is the output of what you have? Also, what does `$image->resize('w=272&h=170')` return? A URL or binary image data?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (untested):

```
if ($image) echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><img src="' . $image->resize('w=272&h=170') . '"/></a>';
```

The result from $image->resize() in wordpress renders the destination... A better solution would be the following:

```
if($image && ($imageResized = $image->resize('w=272&h=170'))) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . $imageResized . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: You not concanate the variable.

Comment: @adder I have updated my answer with a more suitable solution

Comment: What is totally bad, because condition will always executes. You need to use `==` character instead a single `=` for comparison. If you do not compare, then why you use condition?

Comment: The `=` is not being used for comparison. It is being used for assignment, and then the resulting expression is being evaluated. It's a common pattern found in C-like languages.

Comment: @lolka_bolka This is by design, so the function $image->resize isnt executed twice! If you don't know what happens in the code, don't judge it!

Comment: Before you edit, there wasn't there the other condition. @DanielGibbs also tells it to you. So if you can not programming, do not teach others.

Comment: for this one it returns "/> at the end and breaks

<a href="http://domain.com/news/alumni-videos/"><img src="<img width="272" height="170" alt="" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/7.png" />"/></a>

Comment: Uh, @lolka_bolka, I was agreeing with @RichardBernards - he was correct in his usage of `=` - you were misunderstanding it.

Comment: @Adder I have updated the answer... I probably missed something (like a plugin for example) because `$image->resize()` returns a complete HTML in your case...

Comment: @DanielGibbs: What is this line for? `if($imageResized = $image->resize('w=272&h=170') {`. Create a condition what is not a condition. I know, the value will assigned the `$imageResized` so it's not a syntax error, just totally unnecessayr.

Comment: @lolka_bolka read DanielGibbs his reply... It's an assignment which is afterwards processed as an expression... If $imageResized gets to be a faulty value, you can read it as `if(false) {}`

Comment: What i can imagine, he want to add `$image && ` also to his code, but before he did, pressed the save edit. That was what i've reflected.

Comment: @lolka_bolka It assigns the result of `$image->resize(...)` to `$image`, then evaluates `$image` as the condition of the while loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7215323/343486.

Comment: @DanielGibbs See the edits. When he first updated his edit, then there was only 1 condition.

Comment: @lolka_bolka that does not matter... the `if` is still processed like we are trying to explain to you...

Comment: Yes I saw that! It is still valid code! Read the link I posted.

Comment: Ok, i am going to work, this conversation is boring me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($image) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . $image->resize('w=272&h=170') . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Not. Concated with `' .` before `$image-resize` and `. '` after that Use an IDE dude to check for syntax error, and learn basics of PHP strings instead of downvote me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
echo ($image ? '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'. $image->resize('w=272&h=170'). '</a>' : '');
```

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: `echo ($image ? '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'. $image->resize('w=272&h=170'). '</a>' : '');`

Comment: `$image->resize()` can render a faulty result which you didnt capture.